# Get FirebaseListObservable with parameter (AngularFire2, Angular 2)

Tags: typescript, angular, firebase, angularfire, observable

How can I get a list from Firebase using a paramter in the path? Something like:

```
constructor(fire: AngularFire) {
    fire.database.list('/users/:userid');
}
```

My current approach is:

```
constructor(fire: AngularFire) {
    const userData$ = fire.auth
        .flatMap((userData) => fire.database.list(`/users/${userData.uid}`));

    this.userData = userData$ as FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
}
```

But there's still an ordinary `Observable` assigned to `this.userData`. I also couldn't find a way to use queries to achieve that.

I also want `this.userData` to get updated automatically when `userData.uid` changes, hence the use of Observables.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: Hi Andreas, did you manage to solve this issue ? My problem is that when I signout something triggers the call to `/users/${userData.uid}` (but I don't have the permission anymore so it fails). Do you think it's related ? Thx

Comment: No, I didn't. Also I still don't fully understand how Observables work.

Answer (score 0):

There is a known open issue for this in Github. The [issue](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/162) seems to be related to the lift function being used internally by firebaseListObservable. I think it may be fixed in beta.1 but they have not responded to my question about it.